# Single word Palindrome Checker (True or False)

Tags: python

Right now, what I have is a code that I can test a single word whether it is a Palindrome or not. I have to input the word, and it will tell me whether it is a Palindrome (True) or if it is not (False)

I need to create one that Asks for a single word, then provides a True of False based on the word that is typed. This is what i have so far.

I really have no idea how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def isPalindrome(s):
   if len(s) <= 1:
       return True
   else:
       if s[0] != s[len(s)-1]:
           return False
       else:
           return isPalindrome(s[1:len(s)-1])
print(isPalindrome("poop"))
```

Comment: Code Review is for improving code, not when you need help writing it. I've migrated your question to a more appropriate location.

Comment: why don't you just created a reversed version of the string and then check if the two strings are equal?

Comment: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) would like you to name that function `is_palindrome` instead of `isPalindrome`.

Answer (score 20):

Simply create a reversed string and check if both are equal.

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

print(isPalindrome('poop'))
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter (words are usually short) but you should only check both halves for equality (floored-half, because you don't care for the middle letter in odd-length words.)

Answer (score 2):

Also using a reversed string, but can be used in-line, as well  (i.e., doesn't require a function).

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    return word == ''.join(reversed(word))

print is_palindrome('hello') #False
print is_palindrome('racecar') #True
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to get Python to take user input, then there are a couple options available to you. One option is to make your script run from the command line and use a command line argument and the other is to use the raw_input function. Both are implemented in the following code.

```
import sys

def isPalindrome(word):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        inp = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        inp = raw_input("Type a word: ") # Which you might want to strip for white space
    if isPalindrome(inp):
        print inp,"is a palindrome"
    else:
        print inp,"is not a palindrome"
```

Several other people have suggested alternative implementations for isPalindrome that are probably better, but if you are doing this as an assignment and are supposed to use recursion, then keep using yours. Also, the raw_input function can be called anywhere that is convenient in your script and doesn't have to be used when called from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You might try this function:

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    return text[:len(text)//2] == text[:(len(text)-1)//2:-1]
```

Here is example usage for reference:

```
>>> is_palindrome('')
True
>>> is_palindrome('a')
True
>>> is_palindrome('b')
True
>>> is_palindrome('aa')
True
>>> is_palindrome('ab')
False
>>> is_palindrome('ba')
False
>>> is_palindrome('bb')
True
>>> is_palindrome('aaa')
True
>>> is_palindrome('aab')
False
>>> is_palindrome('aba')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

here is mine:

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    word=str(word)
    a=word[::-1]
    if a!=word:
        return False
    elif word=='':
        return False
    else: return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Using string subscripting

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    return all(char == string[-i - 1] for i, char in enumerate(string))
```

Using list reversing

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    to_list = list(string)

    # reverse to_list now
    to_list.reverse()

    # our reversed list should be equal string as a list
    # if string is a palindrome
    return to_list == list(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mine:

```
  def palindrome_checker(word):
      return True if len(word) < 2 else (word[0] == word[-1]) and palindrome_checker(word[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
return (s[:1+len(s)//2]==s[len(s)//2:][::-1])
```

Comment: @Dominique there are 2 cases of palindrome case 1: odd number of letters eg: racecar and case 2: even number of letters eg: noon. and the logic behind is that you get the half part of the string and reverse the next half (ignoring the middle value) and check if they are same. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

For the people doing the palindrome test from testdome.com that takes into account casing, here is my solution:

```
def is_palindrome(word):

wordoriginal = []
wordreversed = []

for i in reversed(word):
    i = i.lower()
    wordreversed.append(i)

for i in word:
    i = i.lower()
    wordoriginal.append(i)

return wordoriginal == wordreversed
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up with, hope it works for you:

```
def palindrome_(word):
    word = input("enter your word Here ")
    return word == word[::-1]

print palindrome_("word")
```

Comment: Which is the difference with stephenmuss's solution ?

Comment: my mistake still a rookie

Comment: just added the users input line